# 'ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here' while creating a Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have created a stored procedure, I was expecting to add the total column which is also a trigger, into  FinalTotal.
**Code:**

Procedure `FINAL_TOTAL`:

```
create procedure FINAL_TOTAL(C IN NUMBER,T OUT NUMBER)
        IS
        BEGIN
        UPDATE Products
        SET FinalTotal = SUM(Total),
        HAVING ProdCustId = C;
        Commit;
        SELECT SUM(FinalTotal) into T FROM Products WHERE ProdCustId = C;
        END;
        /
```

Here, if I write `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` then, still it's giving me the same error.

Trigger `Total`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PROD_TOTAL
    AFTER INSERT ON Products
    BEGIN
    UPDATE Products
    SET Total = ProdPrice * ProdQuantity;
    END;
    /
```

Table `Products`;

```
create table Products
    ( ProdId number primary key,
      ProdNum number not null unique,
      ProdName varchar2(15),
      ProdPrice int,
      ProdQuantity int,
      Total int,
      FinalTotal int,
      ProdCustId int references Customers,
      ProdOrdId int references Orders,
      ProdStoreId int references Stores
    );
```

**Error:**
5/18     PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here.

Since I am a beginner, I don't have that much idea, So If anyone knows why this is happening, then please let me know!!

Comment: *if I write WHERE instead of HAVING then, still it's giving me the same error* : Obviously it's not proper to use HAVING for an UPDATE statement, and even if you want to use WHERE , then need to remove the comma there, which's a typo. Btw, it is not designly correct to hold `Total` and `FinalTotal` values those can already be calculated from the existing values whenever needed.

Comment: @BarbarosOzhan If you know 'what's the proper way of designing this procedure?' then pls let me know, and also, after removing the comma, I am getting the same error. So please help me!!

Comment: "related" questions  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65899704/4808122 https://stackoverflow.com/q/65883948/4808122 https://stackoverflow.com/a/65858908/4808122

Answer (score 1):

Please note first that you example should be *questioned*. You typically  *do not wan't* to store a `customer Id` in a `Product` table as you often sell one `product Id` to  *lot of* customers.

I'm therefore illustrating the concepts on a `ProductSales` table, while leaving only the most relevant attributes.

My main point is *do not* use **triggers** and **procedures** if you may use only plain SQL.

The first concept is the calculation of the `Total Price` - you may use the [virtual column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) to calculate it

```
create table ProductSales
    ( ProdId number primary key,
      ProdPrice int,
      ProdQuantity int,
      Total int generated always as (ProdPrice * ProdQuantity) virtual,
      ProdCustId int  
    );
    
insert into  ProductSales (ProdId, ProdPrice, ProdQuantity,ProdCustId) values (1, 100, 5, 1001);   
insert into  ProductSales (ProdId, ProdPrice, ProdQuantity,ProdCustId) values (2, 50,  1, 1001);
insert into  ProductSales (ProdId, ProdPrice, ProdQuantity,ProdCustId) values (3, 100, 10,1002);
```

After adding some sample data you see, the `Total`column is calculated as expected and defined with the formula in the `CREATE TABLE`.

```
select * from ProductSales;

    PRODID  PRODPRICE PRODQUANTITY      TOTAL PRODCUSTID
---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ----------
         1        100            5        500       1001
         2         50            1         50       1001
         3        100           10       1000       1002
```

The next feature ist the calculation of the *total price per customer*. Here I'd recommend to use an analytic function  in a view as follows

```
create view V_ProductSales as         
select a.*,
sum(TOTAL) over (partition by ProdCustId) as CustTotal
from  ProductSales a;

select * from V_ProductSales;

   PRODID  PRODPRICE PRODQUANTITY      TOTAL PRODCUSTID  CUSTTOTAL
---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100            5        500       1001        550
         2         50            1         50       1001        550
         3        100           10       1000       1002       1000
```

So you get the *customer total* value from the view wihtout storing it in the table (which would violate the [normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization))

This is my final recommendation - get an introductory SQL book learn basic concepts (such as normalization, ER models, CamelCase Identifiers in Oracle, that `price` is not always `Int` datatype etc.) and than start your profesional career.